# MATLAB: subtracting each element in a large vector from each element in another large vector in the fastest way possible

Tags: matlab, vector

here is the code I have, its not simple subtraction.  We want subtract each value in one vector from each value in the other vector, within certain bounds tmin and tmax.  time_a and time_b are the very long vectors with times (in ps).  binsize is just for grouping times in a similar range for plotting.  The longest way possible would be to loop through each element and subtract each element in the other vector, but this would take forever and we are talking about  vectors with hundreds of megabytes up to gb.

```
function [c, dt, dtEdges] = coincidence4(time_a,time_b,tmin,tmax,binsize)
% round tmin, tmax to a intiger multiple of binsize:
if mod(tmin,binsize)~=0
    tmin=tmin-mod(tmin,binsize)+binsize;
end
if mod(tmax,binsize)~=0
    tmax=tmax-mod(tmax,binsize);
end

dt = tmin:binsize:tmax;
dtEdges = [dt(1)-binsize/2,dt+binsize/2];
% dtEdges = linspace((tmin-binsize/2),(tmax+binsize/2),length(dt));
c = zeros(1,length(dt));

Na = length(time_a);
Nb = length(time_b);

tic1=tic;
% tic2=tic1;
% bbMax=Nb;
bbMin=1;
for aa = 1:Na
    ta = time_a(aa);
    bb = bbMin;
    %    tic
    while (bb<=Nb)
        tb = time_b(bb);
        d = tb - ta;
        if d < tmin
            bbMin = bb;
            bb = bb+1;
        elseif d > tmax
            bb = Nb+1;
        else
%             tic
%             [dum, dum2] = histc(d,dtEdges);
            index = floor((d-dtEdges(1))/(dtEdges(end)-dtEdges(1))*(length(dtEdges)-1)+1);

%             toc
            %            dt(dum2)
            c(index)=c(index)+1;
            bb = bb+1;
        end
    end
%     if mod(aa, 200) == 0
%         toc(tic2)
%         tic2=tic;
%     end
end
% c=c(1:end-1);
toc(tic1)
end
```

Comment: Typical sizes of `time_a`, `time_b`? I would assume `tmin`, `tmax` and `binsize` to be scalars?

Comment: correct, typical size is approximately 1x1226018300 so about a billion elements or more.

Comment: Can we even create such an array in MATLAB? I tried doing it on my system and it gave me `out-of-memory` error. Of course it's not a high-end one though.

Comment: also, I forgot to mention that the time_a and time_b vectors are in order, starting with smallest value and increasing. They are basically time stamps for when a photon hits the detector, ordered sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a final answer but a few clue to simplify and accelerate your system:

First, use cached values. For example, in your line:

> index = floor((d-dtEdges(1))/**(dtEdges(end)-dtEdges(1))*(length(dtEdges)-1)**+1);

your loop repeat the same computations every iteration. You can calculate the value before starting the loop, cache it then reuse the stored result:

> cached_dt_constant = (dtEdges(end)-dtEdges(1))*(length(dtEdges)-1) ;

Then in your loop simply use:

> index = floor( (d-dtEdges(1)) / cached_dt_constant +1 ) ;

if you have so many loop iteration you'll save valuable time this way.

Second, I am not entirely sure of what the computations are trying to achieve, but you can save time again by using the indexing power of matlab. By replacing the lower part of your code like this, I get an execution time 2 to 3 time faster (and the same results obviously).

```
Na = length(time_a);
Nb = length(time_b);

tic1=tic;
dtEdge_span = (dtEdges(end)-dtEdges(1)) ;
cached_dt_constant = dtEdge_span * (length(dtEdges)-1) ;

for aa = 1:Na
    ta = time_a(aa);

    d = time_b - ta ;
    iok = (d>=tmin) & (d<=tmax) ;
    index = floor( (d(iok)-dtEdges(1)) ./ cached_dt_constant +1 ) ;
    c(index) = c(index) +1 ;

end
toc(tic1)
end
```

Now there is only one loop to go through, the inner loop has been removed and replaced by vectorized calculation. By scratching the head a bit further there might be a way to do even without the top loop and use only vectorized computations. Although this will require to have enough memory to handle quite big arrays in one go.
If the precision of each value is not critical (I see you round and floor values often), try converting your initial vectors to 'single' type instead of the default matlab 'double'. that would almost double the size of array your memory will be able to handle in one go.

Comment: ok, I agree with the first part.  But on the indexing power of matlab, I think you need to know a little more about the computation.  Well, i see in your code it says d=time_b-ta but ta is a scalar and time_b is a huge vector with many many elements, so that does not work for this computation.  we need to find the values for ta-time_b(bb) within the range tmax to tmin.  then we bin them into binsize divisons of c. Then we will get the histogram if we plot c vs dt

Comment: Matlab allow subtraction of a vector or a matrix by a scalar, which is what you are doing here. The line works perfectly fine. The line will return a vector the size of "time_b". Then the next line will compare each value in this vector to your tmin and tmax and return a vector (still the same size) of logical indices.

Comment: yes, so each time that line is executed it creates a vector of size time_b.  And it does this length(time_b) times, which creates millions of vectors of size time_b, so in the end this ends up increasing the computation time by ALOT, considering it hasnt finished by the time I wrote this, whereas the original way finishes in 20-30 seconds